# Proof without words (about statistics or probability)

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, data-visualization

Are there any well known [proofs without words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words) about statistical theorems like for example the CLT, LLN, or the Gauss-Markov theorem? There are many about mathematics in general (e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103758/490552)), but I have yet to come across one that proves a famous theorem in statistics or probability.

A search on CV for "proof without words" returned exactly [one elegant example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10780/176202).